# Excel VBA extract words from string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string in this format:

```
>word1>longword2>longerword3>word4>anotherword5>
```

In VBA I am looking to extract all words between the characters `>`. Any guidelines will be much appreciated - words contain numbers and special characters and are not fixed in length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code will solve your problem

```
Dim longString as String
longString = "word1>longword2>longerword3>word4>anotherword5>"

Dim arrayString() as String
arrayString = Split(longString, ">")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the split function : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

There is an example at the end of the link.

You need to use something like:

```
Dim TestArray() As String;
TestArray = Split(myString, ">")
```

Comment: This is VB, not VBA (which doesn't allow the assignment in the declaration)